# Where are the installed NPM module's dependencies stored in a React Project?

Tags: npm, dependencies, tinymce, tinymce-5, tinymce-react

So, I have installed a npm module : [`@tinymce/tinymce-react`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tinymce/tinymce-react?activeTab=dependencies). So, now this module's code is stored in `node_modules` folder in the root directory of React Project. It has two dependencies. But, where is the code for dependencies of `@tinymce/tinymce-react` stored?
I tried searching `tinymce` module (which is one of it's dependency) in my project files but I couldn't find it. So, where is the code of `tinymce` module stored?